# Query To IDF Vector

Tags: python

I am having trouble trying to convert a list of query terms into a dict mapping term to inverse document frequency. The formula needed is: 
log(N / df(term)), where N is number of documents and df(term) is the number of documents that term appears in.

def q_to_v(index)

ex.
Input: ["cat", "dog"]

Output: {"cat":0.2, "dog": 0.7}

All help is much appreciated

Comment: It is difficult to answer without seeing the code. Perhaps you could have a look at the gensim library that supports such computations out of the box